# Install psycopg2 on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, django, postgresql, ubuntu, psycopg2

I am trying to install psycopg2 on the server for a Django application inside a virtualenv. I have managed to install it in the past successfully by running this command `sudo apt-get -y install libpq-dev python-dev python2.7-dev` before `pip install psycopg2`. 
But now when I try to execute the first command, it shows the following error.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpq-dev : Depends: libssl-dev but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libkrb5-dev but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: comerr-dev but it is not going to be installed
 python2.7-dev : Depends: libexpat1-dev but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libssl-dev but it is not going to be installed
                 Recommends: libc6-dev but it is not going to be installed or
                             libc-dev
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: have you updated your sources recently ? (a la apt-get update)

Comment: Yes I did `apt-get update` before the command.

Comment: Also this has happened recently on another system too.

Comment: Did you notice the last line? `E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.` You might want to resolve that before you try to install new packages.

Comment: I was able to install other packages(like git, pip).